# What is most common word for the noun "bed"?

Tags: перевод

What is the most common Word when referring to a bed?
I.e., У меня есть две кровати? or is there a better word for the noun "bed"?

Comment: A better question is to explain the difference between, "кровать, постель"

Comment: I don't agree - I have considered this question many times just as he put it: We know there are several words for BED, but the User, and I for that matter, want to know which ones are most commonly used. I couldn't tell you the difference between a hotdog and a frankfurter, but I COULD tell you that most people call it a hotdog! Upvote :)

Comment: @CocoPop Both _кровать_ and _постель_ are commonly used words.

Comment: Кровать. We say "постель" when we mean bed prepared for sleeping

Answer (score 8):

There are two different words in Russian:

- *Кровать* is the piece of furniture
- *Постель* is any place with the bedclothes lying on it (or even just the full set of bedclothes)

They are sometimes interchangeable though. "Я лежу в кровати" and "Я лежу в постели" mean the same.

There are also old words such as *ложе* or *одр* but you normally see them only in the books.

- *Ложе* (cf. "*лежать*" = to lie; "*положить*" = to lay) is an outdated poetic word for *bed*; in common speech it's still in use meaning *stream bed* or *gun stock*
- *Одр* is only usable as a part of the expression: *на смертном одре* = *on deathbed*

Answer (score 2):

There are three words that could match "bed" in English:

- ***Кровать*** - bed as in wooden piece of furniture in everybody's home. Probably your case.
- ***Постель*** - bed as in sheets and covers. Widely used for talking about a place where lovers have fun.
- ***Ложе*** - archaic, don't use it.

Source: I am Russian.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say "кровать" is the most popular one.

Answer (score 0):

*Постель* is more official than *кровать*.
*Ложе* or *одр*? No one says so. And you can't see it in modern books. I forgot when I met it last time.
P.S. Trust me, I'm Russian.

Answer (score 0):

The most common word is кровать. You can use постель when you are talking about place prepared for sleep, as it was sayed above. Actually, as a native speaker, I can say that постель can sound a little bit too intimate, but this is my opinion, not the rule.
Mostly these two words are interchangeable, for example, if yu say "Почему ты ещё в кровати, уже поздно?" it won't be a mistake, even if the person you are talking to is on the sofa.